# Fetch value from array/string

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can I fetch the value "3" from this set of arrays:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" }
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" }
```

The arrays are output from a foreach statement of parenting array, which is:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "St" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "0" }
array(3) { [0]=> string(16) "Fu" [1]=> string(1) "3" [2]=> string(1) "0" }
array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "Pa" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" }
```

Where I am going for the second line value: `"Fu" [1]=> string(1) "3"`

Maybe I am doing it wrong from the first array?

Comment: 1. If these 3 arrays aren't wrapped up into one, then these are 3 different arrays 2. This is PHP 101 how to access an array element

Comment: how to find the array with 3 in it is just 'if( $array[0] == 3 )` in your first example, and `if( $array[1]==3 )` in your second example...however, that's the first chapter of any book on programming.  So, it doesn't make sense that THAT is your problem, which is why I'm asking about the problem...or "What's broken?"  You need to show us the code you are trying and what's not working...NOT the output of the array...unless you really are asking how to do `if( $array[1] == 3 )`, in which case it's already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving us much to go on.  Are the 3 arrays already in a parent array, in an object, etc.?  Below is how to get the # 3 from the 3 arrays...but I'm guessing this is not actually what you are asking, we likely need much more detail...the real problem you are trying to solve.

```
function getThree($arr1, $arr2, $arr3) {
    $array = array();
    $array[] = $arr1;
    $array[] = $arr2;
    $array[] = $arr3;

    foreach( $array AS $subArray ) {
        // whichever condition works for you
        if( $subArray[0] == 'Fu' || $subArray[1] == 3 ) {
            return $subArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of return suggests that this is in a function yet there is not one there.  In this example better to assign the value of $subArray[0] to a variable and break out of the foreach once hit.

Comment: @l0ckm4, he used the word "fetch"...I interpreted that as a return...I don't think it matters until he explains what he wants...but I'll wrap it in a function for your viewing pleasure :-p

Comment: excellent - I am now happy :-) BUT, you forgot to set the three $arr's as arguments to pass into the function lol

Comment: @l0ckm4, yeah, I was considering using `func_get_args` or maybe the `...$param`, but I don't know what version of PHP he has...but guessing at it, I think they might be $GLOBALS, so I probably shouldn't assume yet...guess I'll go with static params.

Comment: assumptions are of course the root of all evil so better to pass to be safe.  Going home now  - have a good one :-)

Comment: Kevin, I have updated the original post to be more detailed. Please have a look at it, and let me know if you need additional information. Thank you!

Comment: @user2282217, that's not changing my answer other than which index I look at to find which value...and I changed it to return the entire selected array...if that works for you, then it's done...if not, then I need to know why not.